# Calculating the density of nearest neighbours

Tags: plotting, number-theory

I am trying to plot this

[image]

which is a numerical simulation of the Montgomery-Odlyzko law for the nontrivial 1st $10^5$ zeros of the Riemann zeta function $ζ(s)$. The solid line is given by `1-(Sin[π x]/(πx))^2`.

The following is what I can't seem to interpret:

> The blue symbols indicate the pair correlation function of normalized spacings $δn=(γ_{n+1}-γ_n)\log(γ_n/2π)/2π$ between two consecutive nontrivial zeros $1/2+iγ_n$ and $1/2+iγ_{n+1},\ n=1\dots10^5)$ of the Riemann zeta function $ζ(s)$.

from [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery%27s_pair_correlation_conjecture).
I have looked at various ways of calculating the density, using `Histogram`, `NearestFunction`, `FindClusters`, etc. but am getting nothing like the image above. I realise that this is largely due to a conceptual misunderstanding, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

## Update

[image]

plotted with

```
DeleteCases[Flatten[Table[Abs[z1 - z2] Log[z2/(2 π)]/(2 π), 
{z1, Take[zz,1000]}, {z2, Take[zz,1000]}]], 0];
Show[ListPlot[HistogramList[%, {0, 3, 0.1}][[2]]/200, 
DataRange -> 3], Plot[1 - (Sin[π u]/(π u))^2, {u, 0, 3}]]
```

using [First $10^5$ zeros](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhezqhstuxk65vk/zz.nb) as `zz`, thanks to [Rahul Narain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul-narain)'s comments below. Unfortunately, my computer won't calculate for $10^5$ zeros, but link left for those that will.

... I am now beginning to appreciate the computational power that would have to be used to generate an image like [this](http://cdn.songshuhui.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/zeta_corr.gif) or [this](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/bober/snaith-zeta-zeros-graph.png)!

Comment: I like your question (+1) because of interesting topic even though I think you are asking about a trivial _Mathematica_ problem. Nevertheless I have no time to answer.

Comment: Thank you. I realise it is trivial in terms of _Mathematica_ computation - sorry! I would really appreciate your assistance if you manage to get time at some point :)

Comment: I assume you've read *Odlyzko*'s paper - all the (mathematical) details of how such a graph is created are in it.

Comment: @rasher - do you have a link?

Comment: @eldo: No, I have it on *JSTOR*, read it long ago. If you have *JSTOR* (I'm sure it's elsewhere too), worth a look.

Comment: In the paper, it refers to the integral of the pair correlation function.  Would one then have to find the derivative for each pair? I am sorry, but I am at a bit of a loss :(

Comment: Using your above link and having a look at the image (you show it without its text) it can be seen that 10^5 zeroes were used to compute it. You overlooked the exponentiation operator.

Comment: Ah - many thanks!

Comment: Would using $10^3$ yield much?

Comment: @martin - better than just 100. Another question is the somehow vague meaning of "normalized spacings". If you could produce a y-axis like in the image you probably would be on the right track.

Comment: As I understand it, normalised spacings are given by $δn=(γ_{n+1}-γ_n)\log(γ_n/2π)/2π$, no?

Comment: @martin - yes, they are. I overlooked this definition in the text. Sorry.

Comment: as well studied as the topic is i'd strongly suspect you can readily find tabulated values for the zeros to work with.

Comment: @ george2079, That would be great - it would certainly make calculations faster, but I don't know what to do with them once I have them :/

Comment: I suggest you look up the actual definition of the pair correlation function. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function): "The radial distribution function (or pair correlation function) is usually determined by calculating the distance between *all* particle pairs and binning them into a *histogram*" (emphasis mine). For example, just taking the first 1000 points (because I didn't want to wait a long time): `zzd = Flatten@Table[Abs[zz[[i]] - zz[[j]]], {i, 2, 1000}, {j, 1, i - 1}]; Histogram[zzd, {0, 3, 0.2}]` http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc3Tw.png

Comment: Thank you :) ... I admit it has had me rather confused!

Comment: Please feel free to add answer & I will accept (though if you wouldn't mind skipping the first sentence, I would be eternally grateful ;)).

Comment: The histogram is supposed to then be "normalized with respect to an ideal gas, where particle histograms are completely uncorrelated" so that the horizontal asymptote is at 1 instead of at about 140 in my plot, but I didn't get around to computing that.

Comment: Yes, I figured that :)

Comment: @martin: You can get a text table of the first 100K zeros [here](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko//zeta_tables/index.html), while there, go to home page, follow publications link, you can get a copy of the original paper if you've not already.

Comment: Yes, thank you. - The limitations are with my computer now - but I understand the concept. Can't plot with 10^5 on my machine - :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like your questions since we seem to be doing similar things.

Note that your code correctly finds the normalized spacings between **all** pairs of zeros. This is what the pair correlation function is, but you only want to plot the normalized spacings up to a limit, usually 3. Values returned by your code, `MartinPairs[t]` where list `t` contains the imaginary parts of the zeta zeros, are mostly considerably larger than this upper limit.

```
MartinPairs[t_List] :=
   DeleteCases[Flatten[
      Table[Abs[z1 - z2] Log[z2/(2 Pi)]/(2 Pi), {z1, t}, {z2, t}]],
      0.];
```

It is much faster to use `Differences[t,1,k]` to return the first differences of the input list of zeros `t` with step increment `k`.

```
NormedZetaZeroSpacing[t_List, k_Integer] := 
   Differences[t, 1, k] * Log[Drop[t, -k]/(2 Pi)]/(2 Pi)
```

Years ago, I constructed and stored a list of the first 40000 zeta zeros with Mathematica. The normalized spacings of these zeros, with steps `k=1` to `k=6`, are shown together in the following plot. The calculation took about 5 s on my machine. For comparison, using `MartinPairs[t]` to find all pair spacings between only the first 1000 zeros took about 7 s.

```
Histogram[Table[NormedZetaZeroSpacing[t, k], {k, 1, 6}], {0, 5, 0.05},
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Zero Spacing", "Number"}]
```

[image: zeta zero correlation histograms]

The `k=6` histogram barely shows in the bottom right corner of the above plot.

The match to the theoretical function is shown below.

```
Histogram[
   Flatten[Table[NormedZetaZeroSpacing[t, k], {k, 1, 8}]], {0, 5, 0.05},
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Normalized Spacing  x", "Number"},
   PlotLabel -> "1-(Sin[\[Pi] x]/(\[Pi] x)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(2\)]\)",
   Epilog -> {Thick, Red,
      Line[Table[{x, 2500 (1 - (Sin[\[Pi] x]/(\[Pi] x))^2)}, {x, 0.1, 5, 0.1}]]}]
```

[image: zeta zero pair correlation]

Comment: works a treat! Note the scaling (where you have `2500` is approx $n/(2\pi^2)$ where $n$ is $\#$ of zeros in sample.

Comment: Works with 2M zeros! [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rzRPq.png)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the upvote, and the scaling tip.